# How does method chaining work in #{flash.keep.message} in Expression Language?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, flash-scope

I have this sample code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{fooBar.foo()}" value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

and in the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class FooBar {
    public String foo() {
        final Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
        flash.put("message", "Hello World");
        return "hello?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

and finally in `hello.xhtml`

```
<h:body>
    #{flash.keep.message}
</h:body>
```

So I go to `index.xhtml`, hit Submit, I get redirected to `hello.xhtml` as expected. And when I refresh the page I still see the message because of the flash.keep behavior which is great.

Now I am trying to understand what is going on so I open up the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html).

There is a [`keep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#keep-java.lang.String-) method in this class, but its return type is `void` and it expects a `String` parameter. So is `#{flash.keep.message}` calling the `keep()` method with the message parameter? I really do not think so, as as far as I know it should have been `#{flash.keep(message)}`, isn't it?

So what is going on in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL resolving can be customized with [`ELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) implementations. There are two EL resolvers involved in evaluating `#{flash.keep.message}`. The first one, the JSF-builtin [`FlashELResolver`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/context/flash/FlashELResolver.java#FlashELResolver) is executed on `#{flash}`. As you can see in its source code (line numbers match Mojarra 2.2.12),

```
216        // and the property argument is "keep"...
217        if (property.toString().equals(FLASH_KEEP_VARIABLE_NAME))
218        {
219            elContext.setPropertyResolved(true);
220          
221            // then this is a request to promote the value
222            // "property", which is assumed to have been previously
223            // stored in request scope via the "flash.now"
224            // expression, to flash scope.
225            result = base;
226            // Set a flag so the flash itself can look in the request
227            // and promote the value to the next request
228            FlashFactory ff = (FlashFactory) 
229                    FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FLASH_FACTORY);
230            ff.getFlash(true);
231            ELFlash.setKeepFlag(facesContext);
232        }
```

the `FlashELResolver` will call `ELFlash.setKeepFlag(facesContext)` (line 231) when the `#{flash.keep}` expression is evaluated. It also sets the property as resolved (line 219), so that the EL context can advance with next property, and it sets the `base` (the `#{flash}`) as evaluated result (line 225), so effectively `#{flash.keep}` returns the very same `#{flash}` object.

And then, when the `message` property is to be evaluated on the result of `#{flash.keep}`, which is essentially still `#{flash}`, but with the "keep" flag set, the EL-builtin [`MapELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/MapELResolver.html) is executed. This is because `#{flash}` is essentially a `Map`, see also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html) (emphasis mine).

> public abstract class Flash
>   extends Object
>   **implements Map<String,Object>**

This calls the `Map#get()` method, which is [customized](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/context/flash/ELFlash.java#ELFlash.get%28java.lang.Object%29) in `Flash` class as below (line numbers match Mojarra 2.2.12):

```
384     public Object get(Object key) {
385         Object result = null;
386 
387         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
388         if (null != key) {
389             if (key.equals("keepMessages")) {
390                 result = this.isKeepMessages();
391             } else if (key.equals("redirect")) {
392                 result = this.isRedirect();
393             } else {
394                 if (isKeepFlagSet(context)) {
395                     result = getPhaseMapForReading().get(key);
396                     keep(key.toString());
397                     clearKeepFlag(context);
398                     return result;
399                 }
400 
401             }
402 
403         }
```

As you can see at line 396, it will call `keep(key)` when the flag is set, as done by `FlashELResolver`.